# jQuery & formData: can't see any value on .asp page

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is driving me crazy.

when I submit the form without JS it works well, but when I submit the form with jQuery Ajax to the .asp page I don't get any error but it doesn't retrieve any value.

the form:

```
    <form id="form-elenco-messaggi" method="post" action="/admin/admin_messaggi.asp" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    ....some input fields...

<button name="action" type="submit" value="MarkAsRead" class="submitFomActions">Mark as read</button>


    </form>
```

The JS performing AJAX request:

```
var urlAjaxPage= '/messaggi-ajax.asp';

$('body').on('click', '#form-elenco-messaggi .submitFomActions', function(e){

            var action      = $(this).val(); //get the button value

            var formData    = new FormData($('form#form-elenco-messaggi')[0]);
            formData.append('action',action); //append button value to formData

            $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: urlAjaxPage,
                     data: formData,
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        error: function () {
                            alert("error");
                        },
                        success: function (response) {

                                alert(response); //here it should show 'action' value from .asp response.write request.form("action")

                                console.log(response);

                         }
                    });

            return false;

    });
```

These are console logs:

```
Headers reply
Cache-Control   private
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Tue, 20 Sep 2016 16:15:35 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/5.0

Headers request
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language it-it,it;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  484
Content-Type    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------251902054217998
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try: 1. check the response of the request in the console and for any errors too. 2. hooking to the `submit` event of the `form`, not the click of the submit button 3. Remove `async: false`

Comment: Does `urlAjaxPage` accept GET instead of POST?  You don't define the action type in your HTML.

Comment: I've checked the response on console and it's empty, but the post is filled:
-----------------------------284402038314262 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mode" trash -----------------------------284402038314262 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="item1" C71EB709-1CD0-4EEA-9107-54B509FFDED2 -----------------------------284402038314262 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="canc1" 1 -----------------------------284402038314262 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action" MarkAsRead -----------------------------284402038314262--

Comment: asp accept POST, you can see method="POST" in between ID and ACTION.
I've removed async: false, but nothing changed.
I'm using that      $('body').on('click', '#form-elenco-messaggi .submitFomActions', function(e){     
because that's an ajax loaded form, how should I change it?

Comment: The element with the class 'submitFomActions' is a different element than the element with the ID 'form-elenco-messaggi'.  Because of bubbling, when you click on the class, you are also clicking on the ID.  It isn't clear what jQuery should do, so maybe it is doing nothing.  Can you add an alert or a console message just inside the 'on click' event, to confirm it is executing?

Comment: 'SubmitFormActions' is a class i use to know which button has been clicked. There are 4 buttons on the form and the operations to be executed on asp page are depending on them.

Comment: I've checked dataForm content on concole.log on submit and it has all the rightvalues, but still can't retrieve the them on .asp page on ajax call, working well without JS though. :(